# Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Tags: c

The code suppose to calculate price for taxi ride.
   For example if I ride 10 km with 2 suitcase it should print 27.2
   and i get 13.00

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>

#define START_PRICE 10.20;

#define PRICE_PER_KM 1.30;

#define PRICE_PER_SUITCASE 2.00;

void main()

{
    double km;

    int suitcase;

    double finalPrice;

    printf("Please enter number of kilometers: ");

    scanf("%lf", &km);

    printf("Please enter number of suitcases: ");

    scanf("%d", &suitcase);

    finalPrice = km*PRICE_PER_KM + suitcase*PRICE_PER_SUITCASE + START_PRICE;

    printf("The total price is: %.2lf\n", finalPrice);

}
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What does it do instead?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve] and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @dok Why all those useless blank lines ? It's good to use blank lines to separate logical blocks, but using systematically a blank line is pointless.

Comment: yea i know, i'm new here and i thought that I need to skip line to write code.. Sorry for that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't add semicolons at the end of lines that are too be expanded by the preprocessor.

So remove the semicolons here:

```
#define START_PRICE 10.20;

#define PRICE_PER_KM 1.30;

#define PRICE_PER_SUITCASE 2.00;
```

so that

```
finalPrice = km*PRICE_PER_KM + suitcase*PRICE_PER_SUITCASE + START_PRICE;
```

doesn't expand to

```
finalPrice = km*1.30; + suitcase*2.00; + 10.20;;
```

and instead expands to

```
finalPrice = km*1.30 + suitcase*2.00 + 10.20;
```

Comment: Great! Good to know that :)

Answer (score 0):

## define is processed by the pre-processor and the compiler doesn't see these statements. So ; is not required at the end of statement.

If you turn your settings on your compiler on you will see it:

> error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]|

Also you should respect the minimal standard and change your void main to int main(void){retunr 0}.
And allways check the return of scanf.

This is your final program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#define START_PRICE 10.20
#define PRICE_PER_KM 1.30
#define PRICE_PER_SUITCASE 2.00

int main(void){
    double km;
    int suitcase;
    double finalPrice;

    printf("Please enter number of kilometers: ");

    if(scanf("%lf", &km) == 1)
    printf("Please enter number of suitcases: ");

    if(scanf("%d", &suitcase) == 1)
    finalPrice = km * PRICE_PER_KM + suitcase * PRICE_PER_SUITCASE + START_PRICE;
    printf("The total price is: %.2lf\n", finalPrice);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Please enter number of kilometers: 10
> Please enter number of suitcases: 5
> The total price is: 33.20
> ```